# update json object in postgresql having text field

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I had a column in PostgreSQL which has text datatype (data text)

the data in this column will be like

```json
[
 {"code":"ABC","Value":"A1"},
 {"code":"Name","Value":"Ramesh"},
 {"code":"Age","paramValue":"24"}
]
```

in the above json I want to update value such as
{"code":"Age","paramValue":"30"}

the data would be like

```json
[
 {"code":"ABC","Value":"A1"},
 {"code":"Name","Value":"Ramesh"},
 {"code":"Age","paramValue":"30"}
]
```

since it  TEXT field I tries different ways but couldn't succeed

I tried selecting first

```
SELECT id, data ::json->'"code":"ABC"' as name 
  FROM my_table;
```

I am getting error ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json DETAIL: Expected "," or "}", but found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below Query:

```
with cte as (
             select id, '{'||b-1||', paramValue}' "path_" 
               from test, 
                    jsonb_array_elements(data::jsonb) with ordinality t(a,b)
              where a->>'code'='Age'
)
update test t1 
   set data=jsonb_set(t1.data::jsonb,path_::text[],'"30"'::jsonb) 
  from cte 
 where t1.id=cte.id
```

Note: Above solution will only if value in field `data` is proper `JSON` and there is only one object having 'code' as `Age` per  array`{"code":"Age","paramValue":"30"}`

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9e8244c43836aebe8279e60ea762df38)